# How do I disable all windows hotkeys?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, hotkeys

Same as title, want to kill alt-tab, etc.

Comment: Autohotkey could remap many of them, but some are hardcoded, such as control+alt+delete, though you can remove any security concerns with the policy manager.

Comment: If you are doing this to stop users controlling *their* machines, please don't. Application creators who think they own *my* machine should have nasty things done to them. If you want to configure a system for a kiosk, use some software designed for that purpose (and don't try and reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this reference](http://www.pc1news.com/disabling-the-windows-hotkeys-549.html),

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NoWinKeys
```

Set to disable, Reset to enable.

You will also find apps [like this one](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/disable-or-enable-windows-hotkeys-in-one-click/), but if it is a simple registry change,
it is better to skip executables for it.

Comment: I am getting complaints that this is still allowing alt-tab in vista.

Answer (score 2):

Well, ask a question at a time, for the one in the title:

The registry below will work for windows hotkeys, if you are thinking of hotkeys for a particular window (application) then you just have to check the application's settings.

As for hiding title bars, it kind of seems you are looking for something like [hideanywindow](http://www.hideanywindow.com/)

If you want to do it yourself (coding) you can try having a go at reading the [win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383749(VS.85).aspx)

To disable hotkeys:

> User Key:
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
>   Explorer] System Key:
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
>   Explorer] Value Name: NoWinKeys Data
>
> Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value) Value
>   Data: (0 = disable restriction, 1 =
>   enable restriction)

found at: [pctools](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/549/)

Comment: @Ric, the question does not suggest interest in hiding titlebars.