# Disable Windows Hotkeys

Tags: windows, hotkeys

how could I disable the Windows hotkeys? I need the button to work for a virtual machine, but the windows hotkeys are overriding my vm input and locking my actual computer and such.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows key shortcuts can be disabled using the [group policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) settings.

You can start the group policy editor by entering gpedit.msc in the search/run field on the start menu (it's also accessible from the MMC as a snap-in if you wish to limit your changes to a specific user; see the "Create a custom management console" section on [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c7ecc7d-8784-4b8d-ba1f-ba1882ba8374)).

To disable Windows hotkeys, set *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer > Turn off Windows+X hotkeys* to Disabled.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) is only available in Professional or higher Windows editions. As a workaround you can [edit the registry directly](http://superuser.com/questions/40004/how-do-i-disable-all-windows-hotkeys).

Comment: this is for windows 8. I've tried theses and they don't work.

Comment: ErraticFox, what specifically didn't work? Also, what version of Windows 8 do you have? As and31415 mentioned, group policy is only available in Professional and up, but you should be able to edit the registry in any edition using `regedit`.